# Credit card payment method

Tags: c#, asp.net, credit-card, payment

I'm creating a online webshop using ASP .net and C#. The website is supposed to receive payment by master card, visa, paypal, and e-transfer. Any reference how can I do that, esp for master card and visa. Is it done via web service? Do i hv to use a payment gateway? Is it possible to connect directly to MC and visa? I totally have no clue on this. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Yes you have to use a payment gateway. Banks provide such services. [Also Paypal](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/aspnet/paypal_c_aspnet.aspx).

Answer (score 2):

I suggest that you use a 3rd party API to handle payments :)
Paypal would be a good choice :)

Take a look at the Paypal SDK here
https://cms.paypal.com/us/cgi-bin/?cmd=_render-content&content_ID=developer/library_download_sdks

And you might be interested in the Direct Payment API Paypal
https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=_dcc_hub-outside

Answer (score 0):

As others have said you need to use payment gateway such as WorldPay or PayPal.

I personally chose Paypal due to the wealth of information out there regarding how to implement the payment system into web sites using PHP, JSP, ASP.NET etc...

Plus Paypal offers a good range of packages to suit your needs - you'll also be able to take advantage of their 'IPN' option (Instant Payment Notification).

The Paypal IPN service will make a call to a special asp.net file that you specify on your server everytime a payment is made from your web site... within this call the IPN will send over a bunch of data such as the order number, payee name etc.... you can these use this data to update your database tables such as 'Payment Status', its a great feature!